# How can I create CLI app such as ng which is installed globally into the system?

Tags: javascript, npm, command-line-interface

When I install

```
npm i ng -g
```

how does it understand the path for installation?

Actually I want to create the app which is installing and working the similar way

Answer (score 0):

When you run `npm install --global`, this is usually (not always) for packages that expose a CLI. If this is the case you can use the handy UNIX `which` command to find out where it is.

For example, by default when you install NodeJs, `npm` is intsalled as a global package.
Therefore you are virtually guaranteed to find it, like so:

```sh
$ which npm 
/home/bguiz/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin/npm
```

Your path will depend on a number of factors, such as your operating system, which method you used to install node, currently set environment variables, symlinks, etc. Whatever it is, `ls` that path without the `bin/npm` at the end.

```sh
$ ls /home/bguiz/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/
bin  CHANGELOG.md  include  lib  LICENSE  README.md  share
```

This is the "global" node directory.

Back to your original question, about where `ng` is installed.
Add `node_modules/${PACKAGE_NAME}` to the global node directory, and `ls` that.
In my example this would be:

```sh
$ ls /home/bguiz/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/ng
ls: cannot access '/home/bguiz/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/lib/node_modules/ng': No such file or directory
```

I do not have `ng` installed globally, so the above `ls` command fails. But in your case, you should see the contents of the `ng` package installation.